# ParallelTable vs. Table: Parallel gives NMinimize:nnum error

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization

I have run into an issue where I am getting nnum errors when I use `ParallelTable`, which I do not get when I use `Table` (and even though I have distributed the definitions to the kernels).

EDIT: As requested, here is a "more minimal" example:

```
Module1[n_] := Module[{y, x, s}, 
  s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[n*x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}];
  With[{X = (y /. s[[1]])[x] /. x -> #}, X &]
]

Module2[n_, x_] := Module[{Mys},
  Mys[X_] = Module1[n][X];
  First@NMaximize[{Mys[X], 0 < X < x}, X]
]
```

The following code runs fine:

```
test1 = Table[Module2[i, 20], {i, 1, 5}]
```

But this does not:

```
DistributeDefinitions["Global`"];
test2 = ParallelTable[Module2[i, 20], {i, 1, 5}]
```

The necessary ingredients to reproduce the problem seem to be:

1) A module which uses NDSolve and returns a pure function

2) A second module which uses NMinimize or NMaximize on that function.

In this toy example, there's no reason to introduce two modules (as compared to doing everything in one module); however, in my actual project this is not desirable.

ORIGINAL EXAMPLE: The problem makes use of the following modules:

```
mpl = 1/Sqrt[6.70837*10^-39]
gsT = 106.75

aANDρr[ΛI_, ΓI_, tf_] := Module[{s},
 s = NDSolve[{as'[t] == as[t]*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2)(ρrs[t] + ΛI^4/as[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])], 
   ρrs'[t] + 4*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2) (ρrs[t] + ΛI^4/as[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])] ρrs[t] == ΓI ΛI^4/as[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t], 
             as[0] == 1, ρrs[0] == 0}, {as, ρrs}, {t, 0, tf}];
       Return[{With[{x = (as /. s[[1]])[t] /. t -> #1}, x &], 
       With[{x = (ρrs /. s[[1]])[t] /. t -> #1}, x &]}];
       ];

       UniverseEvolve[ΛI_, ΓI_, tfmini_: 0] := Module[{tfmin, HI, ti, tR, tf, s,(*ρI,*)H, Trad, T, TR, Tmax, aANDρrRESULTS, a, ρr},
          tfmin = tfmini;
          HI = Sqrt[(8 π*ΛI^4)/(3 mpl^2)];
          ti = 2/3 Sqrt[3/(8 π)] mpl/ΛI^2;
          tR = 1/ΓI;
          tf = Max[100 tR, 100 ti, tfmin]; 

          aANDρrRESULTS = aANDρr[ΛI, ΓI, tf];
          a[t_] = aANDρrRESULTS[[1]][t];
          ρr[t_] = aANDρrRESULTS[[2]][t];
          H[t_] = a'[t]/a[t];
          Trad[ρ_] = (30/(π^2 gsT) ρ)^(1/4);
          T[t_] = Trad[ρr[t]];
          TR = Trad[ρr[tR]] ;
          Tmax = NMaximize[{T[t], 0.1 ti < t < 10 ti}, t][[1]];

          Return[{HI,
             With[{x = H[t] /. t -> #1}, x &],
             With[{x = T[t] /. t -> #1}, x &],
             Tmax,
             TR,
             ti,
             tf}];
          ]
```

The following runs without any errors:

```
Table[UniverseEvolve[10^15, 10^i], {i, 6, 10}];
```

However, the following does not:

```
DistributeDefinitions["Global`"];
ParallelTable[UniverseEvolve[10^15, 10^i], {i, 6, 10}];
```

In particular, each kernel generates a large number of NMaximize::nnum errors, and I cannot figure out why.  (Note that the notebook's context is indeed global.)  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Happens in Kubuntu 16.04 with Mma 11 too.

Comment: Can you produce a *minimal* example please?  See http://sscce.org/ for guidance.

Comment: @Szabolcs, while the original code is well beneath the 100 lines suggested on that page, I've written an even more minimal example for you.

Comment: @LaurenPearce It's not about me personally.  The new example considerably increases the chance that someone will take the time to look at the problem and maybe find a solution.  I reduced it a bit more.  +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to that you assigned the slot `#` outside the Function `()&`. You can avoid these issues by putting the slot `#` inside the `Function[]` as

```
Module1[n_] := Module[{y, x, s}, 
    s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[n*x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}];
    Function[Evaluate[(y /. s[[1]])[#]]] 
]
```

If you just want to return the interpolating function, you can also simply write

```
Module1[n_] := Module[{y, x, s}, 
    s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[n*x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}][[1]];
    y /. s
]
```

to avoid any confusion about `#`.

Both methods will run fine in the `ParallelTable[]`.

```
DistributeDefinitions["Global`"];
test2 = ParallelTable[Module2[i, 20], {i, 1, 5}]
(* returns {1.12259, 1.0692, 1.04819, 1.03696, 1.02997} *)
```

---

For the longer example, you can do it by

```
aANDρr[ΛI_,ΓI_,tf_]:= Module[{s},
    s = NDSolve[{
    as'[t] == as[t]*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2)(ρrs[t] + ΛI^4/as[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])],
    ρrs'[t] + 4*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2) (ρrs[t] + ΛI^4/as[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])] 
        ρrs[t] == ΓI ΛI^4/as[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t],
    as[0] == 1, ρrs[0] == 0}, {as, ρrs}, {t, 0, tf}][[1]];
    {as/.s, ρrs/.s}
]
```

and

```
UniverseEvolve[ΛI_, ΓI_, tfmini_: 0] := 
Module[{tfmin, HI, ti, tR, tf, s,(*ρI,*)H, Trad, T, TR, Tmax, aANDρrRESULTS, a, ρr}, 
    tfmin = tfmini;
    HI = Sqrt[(8 π*ΛI^4)/(3 mpl^2)];
    ti = 2/3 Sqrt[3/(8 π)] mpl/ΛI^2;
    tR = 1/ΓI;
    tf = Max[100 tR, 100 ti, tfmin];

    aANDρrRESULTS = aANDρr[ΛI, ΓI, tf];
    a[t_] = aANDρrRESULTS[[1]][t];
    ρr[t_] = aANDρrRESULTS[[2]][t];
    H[t_] = a'[t]/a[t];
    Trad[ρ_] = (30/(π^2 gsT) ρ)^(1/4);
    T[t_] = Trad[ρr[t]];
    TR = Trad[ρr[tR]];
    Tmax = NMaximize[{T[t], 0.1 ti < t < 10 ti}, t][[1]];
    {HI, Function[Evaluate[H[#]]], Function[Evaluate[T[#]]], Tmax, TR, ti, tf}
]
```

Comment: This works- thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just an extended comment.  A smaller example demonstrating a closely related (though not entirely identical) problem is the following:

```
In[1]:= fun[] := f[x] & /. x -> #    

In[2]:= fun[][z]    
Out[2]= f[z]    

In[3]:= ParallelEvaluate[fun[][z], 1]    
Out[3]= f["KernelObject"[1, "local"]]
```

`Out[3]` should be identical to `Out[2]`, but it isn't.

Hope fully this will help in debugging the issue.

A [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint.html) reveals than when this expression is evaluated on a subkernel, the slot (`#`) is somehow replaced by this:

[image]

Compare `TracePrint[fun[][x]]` with `ParallelEvaluate[TracePrint[fun[][x]], 1]`.

A more trivial example is

```
slot[] := #    
ParallelEvaluate[slot[], 1]

(* "KernelObject"[1, "local"] *)
```

or the `TracePrint` equivalent.

The root cause of all of this is very likely that the free `#` (i.e. slot not bound to a pure function) gets at some point injected into the expression of some pure function, which then replaces it with an argument.  I seem to remember some StackExchange posts dealing with similar problems, and will try to search for them.